# Java EJB2 JNDI Look Up Fail when migrating from Jboss 4 to Jboss 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jndi

I have an EJB2 application running on JBOSS 4.2.3GA and the look up is working fine using: `java:comp/env/ejb/MyEJB`.

When moving to JBOSS AS 6.1.Final, it suddenly broke with exception NameNotFoundException.

JNDI View does show the EJB being bound to the correct tree. Putting a breakpoint before lookup I was able to watch and confirm that it is bound. Using `context.list("java:comp/env/ejb")`, I was able to see MyEJB in the iterator. Using `context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb")` also works. However `context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/MyEJB")` shows NamingException on the watch window (and NameNotFoundException when running the actual code).

Is there anything changed that I do not know about? It's very difficult to find information on this EJB stuff and any information I found suggest either confirms what I'm doing it right or says to use `ejb/MyEJB` which doesn't work at all.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate your help.

ejb-jar.xml:

```
<session>
        <ejb-name>AdminSessionEJB</ejb-name>
        <local-home>com.admin.ejb.business.AdminSessionHome</local-home>
        <local>com.admin.ejb.business.AdminSession</local>
        <ejb-class>com.admin.ejb.business.AdminSessionEJB</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>ejb/UserEJB</ejb-ref-name>
            <ejb-ref-type>Entity</ejb-ref-type>
            <local-home>com.admin.ejb.entity.UserHome</local-home>
            <local>com.admin.ejb.entity.User</local>
            <ejb-link>UserEJB</ejb-link>
        </ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>ejb/UniqueKeyEJB</ejb-ref-name>
            <ejb-ref-type>Entity</ejb-ref-type>
            <local-home>com.framework.ejb.entity.UniqueKeyHome</local-home>
            <local>com.framework.ejb.entity.UniqueKey</local>
            <ejb-link>UniqueKeyEJB</ejb-link>               
        </ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>ejb/UserGroupEJB</ejb-ref-name>
            <ejb-ref-type>Entity</ejb-ref-type>
            <local-home>com.admin.ejb.entity.UserGroupHome</local-home>
            <local>com.admin.ejb.entity.UserGroup</local>
            <ejb-link>UserGroupEJB</ejb-link>
        </ejb-local-ref>
</session>
```

jboss.xml:

```
<enterprise-beans>
        <entity>

        <ejb-name>UserEJB</ejb-name>
        <local-jndi-name>ejb/UserHome</local-jndi-name>
        <read-only>false</read-only>
        <configuration-name>UserEJB Container Configuration</configuration-name>            
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>ejb/UserGroupEJB</ejb-ref-name>
            <local-jndi-name>ejb/UserGroupHome</local-jndi-name>
        </ejb-local-ref>
    </entity>
</enterprise-beans>
```

Comment: Please show the XML declaration for the EJB declaration from your ejb-jar.xml file and the corresponding XML from your jboss.xml file.

Comment: I have posted the part for just UserEJB, which is what I'm testing. Let me know if you need more. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to remove `<local-jndi-name>ejb/UserHome</local-jndi-name>` from the jboss.xml file because the container should figure the linking up from the  `<ejb-link>UserEJB</ejb-link>` entries in the ejb-jar.xml file. Additionally it does not make sense to put `<ejb-local-ref>...</ejb-local-ref>` in the jboss.xml file either (unless you're trying to override the content of the ejb-jar.xml file).

Comment: Same error after removing 1 or both of the above mentioned. Looking at the log, after removing `<local-jndi-name>`, JBOSS automatically gives it a new name `Bound EJB LocalHome 'UserEJB' to jndi 'local/UserEJB@1161245188'`. This is how it would be before removing: `Bound EJB LocalHome 'UserEJB' to jndi 'ejb/UserHome'`

Comment: Well, I went ahead and removed everything from `jboss.xml` so that all EJBs are generated by JBOSS with name `NameEJB@xxxxxxxxxx`, then store all of these name on first access with `key = NameEJB` and `value = NameEJB@xxxxxxxxx` then looking up base on value. I really appreciate you spending your time looking into my problem. Thank you very much, Steve.

Comment: I think you missed something important: When you have an `ejb-local-ref` with `<ejb-ref-name>ejb/UserGroupEJB</ejb-ref-name>`, the corresponding JNDI lookup name is `java:comp/env/ejb/UserGroupEJB`. There is always an implicit `java:comp/env/` in front of the `ejb-ref-name` element value.

Comment: I tried lookup with both but other one gives a NamingNotFound. When I did `list()` on the other path, it listed all the EJBs as `javax.naming.LinkRef` class, but when I did a list on local, it listed all the EJBs as `sun.identity.Proxy` (something with sun and proxy, I forgot the exact name) class. The only way I was able to use `java:comp/env` is to configured `<local-jndi-name>` in `jboss.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the newer JBoss/WildFly versions don't cope with old deployment descriptors very well.

If you update the ejb-jar.xml schema from:

```
    <ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd"
      version="2.1">
```

to at least:

```
    <ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
```

then it should work as advertised.

You can find a working example on GitHub at [javaee14-ejb-demo](https://github.com/sfcoy/javaee14-ejb-demo)

Comment: My apologies, you put so much time into testing all these scenarios. I tried them but run into many problems after switching from 2_0.dtd to 3_0.xsd, and fixing 1 leads to another so I have to move with the previous solution for now. The end target is wildfly 10.0 and I'm certain I will run into this again. That's when I will be playing with it. Again, I really appreciate your time, Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Get the EJB in the context (in this case using class name):

```
public static <T> T getInstance(final Class<T> type) {
    T result = null;
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        BeanManager manager = (BeanManager) ctx.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = manager.getBeans(type);
        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) manager.resolve(beans);
        if (bean != null) {
            CreationalContext<T> context = manager.createCreationalContext(bean);
            if (context != null) {
                result = (T) manager.getReference(bean, type, context);
            }
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I added the `cdi-api-1.2.jar` and try your snippet anyway but `ctx.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager") returns null`. Do I need to set up configuration in the xml for the BeanManager? If this BeanManager can somehow get the EJB, it must be doing the same lookup in the background, correct? then in that case, wouldn't it just be that my lookup string is incorrect?